# Dynamic array of linked lsts

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list, malloc

I've been trying to figure this out for the last 3 days and searching but couldnt find any example to help me out.

I have an array of linked lists and I manage to write inside the struct dynamically inside a function and manage to write its content. Once I get to to main function, I cant retrieve the content. This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 5

typedef struct tabuleiro tabela, *ptabela; //Estrutura do tabuleiro
struct tabuleiro{
    int col;
    int cont;
    int fil;
    ptabela prox;
};

void mostra_info(ptabela p[])
{
    int aux = 0;

    ptabela atual = p;

    for(aux = 0; aux < MAX; aux++){

        while(atual != NULL ){
            printf("F:%d - C:%d \n", aux, atual->col);
            atual = atual->prox;
        }
    }



}

ptabela preenche(int col,int fila, int op){

    ptabela novo;

    novo = malloc(sizeof(tabela));
    if(novo == NULL){
        printf("Erro na memória - FH-Preenche");
        return NULL; //MANDAR MENSAGEM DE ERRO DE ALOCACAO
    }

    novo->col = col;
    novo->fil = fila;
    novo->cont = op;
    novo->prox = NULL;

   return novo;
}

ptabela colocar_peca(ptabela p[], int op){

    ptabela atual, ant, novo;

    int y;
    int fila, col;

    // ant = NULL; CODIGO DO PROF POWERPOINT
    printf("Fila: ");
    scanf("%d",&fila);

    printf("Coluna: ");
    scanf("%d",&col);

    atual = p[fila];
    ant = NULL;

    while(atual != NULL && p[fila]->col == col){
        ant = atual;
        atual = atual->prox;
        printf("entrou while - colocar preca");
    }
    novo = preenche(col, fila, op);

    if(novo == NULL)
        printf("erro de alocao adicionar peca.");

    if(ant == NULL){
        novo->prox = atual;
        p[fila] = novo;
    }else {
        novo->prox = atual;
        ant->prox = novo;
    }

    printf("Fila: %d Coluna: %d Cont: %d \n", p[fila]->fil, p[fila]->col, p[fila]->cont);
    printf("Fila: %d Coluna: %d Cont: %d \n", novo->fil, novo->col, novo->cont);
    printf("\n");

    return p;
}


int Play_menu(ptabela pos[]){

    ptabela novo;

    int op ,i;
    int fila, col;
    while(op != 10){
    printf("1 - Place a green piece.\n");
    printf("2 - Place a yellow piece.\n");
    printf("3 - Place a red piece.\n");
    
    printf("Escolha uma jogada: ");
    scanf("%d", &op);


    switch(op){
        case 1:

          pos = colocar_peca(pos, op);


                printf("Fila: %d Coluna: %d Cont: %d \n", novo->fil, novo->col, novo->cont);




        break;

        case 2:
            colocar_peca(pos, op);
        break;

        case 3:
            colocar_peca(pos, op);
        break;

        case 4:
            mostra_info(pos);
        break;



    }
    }
    return op;
}


int main(void){

    ptabela pos[MAX] = {NULL};

    Play_menu(pos);



}
```

The function colocar_peca is to get the values I need for the struct. Once i get them, I send them to function preenche to grab the memory and then return it and place it back in function colocar_peca. Function Mostra_info is suppose to show the information of each piece i add to the structure.

Result 1:

```
1 - Colocar uma peca verde.
2 - Trocar uma peca verde por uma peca amarela.
3 - Trocar uma peca amarela por uma peca vermelha.
4 - Colocar uma pedra.
5 - Adicionar Linha.
6 - Adicionar Coluna.
Escolha uma jogada: 1
Fila: 2
Coluna: 2
Fila: 2 Coluna: 2 Cont: 1
Fila: 2 Coluna: 2 Cont: 1

Fila: 11671816 Coluna: 0 Cont: 0
```

Result 2:

```
1 - Colocar uma peca verde.
2 - Trocar uma peca verde por uma peca amarela.
3 - Trocar uma peca amarela por uma peca vermelha.
4 - Colocar uma pedra.
5 - Adicionar Linha.
6 - Adicionar Coluna.
Escolha uma jogada: 1
Fila: 3
Coluna: 4
Fila: 3 Coluna: 4 Cont: 1
Fila: 3 Coluna: 4 Cont: 1

Fila: 0 Coluna: 0 Cont: 0
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, remove all the code that is not necessary for reproducing the problem. Also, please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. This is especially important in this case as your code has non-English in it which makes it hard for most people on SO to follow.

Comment: @kaylum i do have the minimal reproducible example. I'll edit and specify a little better.

Comment: `novo` is not initialized in `Play_menu`.

Comment: Please give the **exact** input, expected result and actual result. That is, show the log of running the program, highlight what is wrong with it and show what it should be instead.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yeah sorry, ill edit it but it still doesnt work.

Comment: `*ptabela;` do not use typedef pointers. They are confusing.

Comment: @KamilCuk its the way im learning :(
how would you recommend ?

Comment: Just write `tabela*` instead. I personally like structs, I would write `struct tabuleiro*`. `for(aux = 0; aux < MAX; aux++){

        while(atual != NULL )` `actual` is the same each loop. Most probably ther's a `actual = p[aux]` missing. Also `ptabela atual = p;` is invalid - it's assigning `struct tabuleiro**` to `struct tabuleiro*` - something that your compiler should warn you about. Make sure to enable compiler warnings and try to solve them all.

Comment: Please just run the program, copy exactly what is on the terminal and paste it into the question.

Comment: @kaylum sorry. just pasted it

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah, thats what i saw most people doing but I still havent managed translating it and applying it to my work

Comment: Don't write code using local language words for variables, functions, etc. Use english terms so that others can understand the code.

Comment: The posted output can't be from the posted code...

Comment: @4386427 well, it is !!! run it ....

Comment: @4386427 its our local language .... thats why its like that

Comment: @kaylum did you manage to figure it out ?! im desperate